# Wrap react blackbox block components and add dom listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that wraps a variety of other react components using a standard interface. The wrapped components are "blackbox" plugins because I may not be their author. So there is an interface definition of what these components need to be capable of in order to "fit" the plugin wrapper.

Now I need those plugins to render styles or event listeners defined by the plugin wrapper.

Unfortunately the plugin wrapper cannot simply add a react html element around the plugins because such an element might end up between `<tr>`s and `<table>`s, or between `<td>`s and `<tr>`s which is invalid.

I should impose something on the plugin interface definition that tells plugin to render the passed dom props on their top level html element, and I'm wondering what that definition could be.

An attempt at requiring the plugin's top level component to be a html element failed as I don't know of a way of distinguishing react html elements from functional components.

Does anyone know of a distinction, or is there anything else I can do? Perhaps something to do with refs?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'll just require the plugins to implement a `domProps` prop and make them responsible for adding the passed props into their top-level dom.

If anyone has a nice idea how to verify that passed `domProps` indeed get rendered by the plugins and throw an error if not, I'll accept this as an answer.